# Upload all camera photos into a skydrive folder in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How do I sync all of my camera roll photos in my windows phone 7 to skydrive? I want to sync all of them into a folder on skydrive. But I don't know how to go about it. 
Any sample codes for referencing would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this is built into your phone. Open Pictures, and click settings from the menu. There's an option "Automatically upload to SkyDrive".

Answer (score 1):

You may find one of the articles on Reddit wp7dev to be useful :-

http://www.reddit.com/r/wp7dev/search?q=skydrive&restrict_sr=on